# Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server. on Django, Apache, Centos7

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm using Centos 7. I create a django project under `/home/WEFORUM/admshapersdev/stargate/` and create a wsgi file in `/home/WEFORUM/admshapersdev/stargate/stargate`

The Django.conf

```
Alias /static /home/WEFORUM/admshapersdev/stargate/landingpage/static
<Directory /home/WEFORUM/admshapersdev/stargate/landingpage/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/WEFORUM/admshapersdev/stargate/stargate>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
WSGIDaemonProcess stargate python-path=/home/WEFORUM/admshapersdev/stargate:/home/WEFORUM/admshapersdev/stargate/stargateenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup stargate
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/WEFORUM/admshapersdev/stargate/stargate/wsgi.py
```

The structure and rights of the project folder:
../stargate

```
drwxr-xr-x. 6 admshapersdev apache       4096 Aug 17 22:47 landingpage/
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 admshapersdev apache        806 Aug 17 21:42 manage.py*
-rw-r--r--. 1 admshapersdev apache        464 Aug 17 22:42 requirements.txt
drwxr-xr-x. 4 admshapersdev apache       4096 Aug 18 01:08 stargate/
drwxr-xr-x. 5 admshapersdev apache         77 Aug 17 21:41 stargateenv/
drwxr-xr-x. 2 admshapersdev apache          6 Aug 17 21:52 static/
```

../stargate/stargate

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 admshapersdev apache          0 Aug 17 21:42 __init__.py
drwxr-xr-x. 2 admshapersdev apache       4096 Aug 18 01:09 __pycache__/
-rw-r--r--. 1 admshapersdev domain users 3555 Aug 18 01:08 settings.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 admshapersdev apache       3676 Aug 18 01:05 settings.py_1
drwxr-xr-x. 9 admshapersdev apache         91 Aug 17 22:49 static/
-rw-r--r--. 1 admshapersdev apache        259 Aug 17 22:38 urls.py
-rwxr--r--. 1 admshapersdev apache        394 Aug 18 00:49 wsgi.py*
```

But each time I try to reach my page, I am having this error in apache log:

```
[core:error] [pid 22477] (13)Permission denied: [client 192.168.140.179:63696] AH00035: access to /favicon.ico denied (filesystem path '/home/WEFORUM/admshapersdev/stargate') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path, referer: http://stargate0.weforum.local/admin
```

Does anyone know how to handle this? thank you for suggestions.
I move the project to /var/www but now I am having this:
`[Sat Aug 18 07:43:49.987481 2018] [core:notice] [pid 20202] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Sat Aug 18 07:58:19.927287 2018] [core:error] [pid 20205] (13)Permission denied: [client 192.168.140.179:49188] AH00035: access to /admin/ denied (filesystem path '/var/www/stargate') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path, referer: http://stargate0.weforum.local/admin/login/?next=/admin/
[Sat Aug 18 07:58:24.840377 2018] [core:error] [pid 20205] (13)Permission denied: [client 192.168.140.179:49188] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/var/www/stargate') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
[Sat Aug 18 07:58:29.481225 2018] [core:error] [pid 20205] (13)Permission denied: [client 192.168.140.179:49188] AH00035: access to /admin/ denied (filesystem path '/var/www/stargate') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path, referer: http://stargate0.weforum.local/admin/login/?next=/admin/`

Comment: Where is your `favicon.ico` placed?

Comment: What do you get for ``ls -lasd /home/WEFORUM``? The home directory may not be readable to others. Another possibility is that SELinux is setup to block Apache from being able to access files under your home directory.

Comment: BTW, do not use ``python-path`` to point at Python ``site-packages``. That is not the recommended way of using a virtual environment. Read docs at https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html for recommended way.

Comment: Is the owner of that path in the www group?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton `ls -lasd /home/WEFORUM` gives `4 drwxr-xr-x. 10 root root 4096 Jun 20 13:24 /home/WEFORUM`

Comment: @guillermochamorro `faicon.ico` is located in 2 files: `./stargateenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/static/rest_framework/docs/img/favicon.ico
./stargate/static/rest_framework/docs/img/favicon.ico`

Comment: Try moving your project outside of your home directory. Under ``/var/www/projects`` or other sub directory under the normal area where Apache would serve files from, and so have access based on SELinux profile.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I moved the file to /var/www but still not working, I put the apache error log above. ls -alF on www gives : `drwx--x---.  5 root root   46 Aug 18 07:40 www/`

Comment: If that is permissions on ``/var/www`` that looks wrong. Apache user wouldn't be able to see inside of that directory. Never seen that being standard permissions on that directory.